# Смысл использования манипуляторов(с++) flush, unitbuf, ends

Tags: c++, flush

По ходу изучения ввода-вывода, возник вопрос - зачем явно сбрасывать буфер, если за вас это делает программа? Что это дает?
Когда и зачем стоит использовать flush, ends и т.д?
В чем смысл unitbuf, когда и зачем использовать его?

Comment: Там, где программа это не делает?... :)

Comment: @Harry, например?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[flush](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) использую где необходимо. Например выходной поток сбрасывает по концам строк. Для индикатора прогресса его надо сбрасывать раньше. Пример ниже.

[unitbuf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/unitbuf) не использую. Вместо него `flush` где нужно. Причина - `unitbuf` влияет на поток глобально, что может изменить смысл или скорость работы других кусков программы. Чтобы этого не было, нужно сохранить текущую установку, выставить свою, вывести что надо, вернуть всё как было. Много мороки, без `unitbuf` проще.

[ends](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ends) не использую. `std::cout << '\0';` проще и прямолинейнее. [endl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) тоже не использую. Для обычного потока вывода `std::cout << '\n';` работает также. Если требуется ещё гарантированно сбросить буфер, добавляю `flush`.

Пример с `flush`:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main() {

    auto wait = []{
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    };

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
        std::cout << "without flush ";
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
            wait();
            std::cout << '.';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';

        std::cout << "with flush    ";
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
            wait();
            std::cout << '.' << std::flush;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ print.cpp 
>
> $ ./a.out 
> without flush ....................
> with flush    ....................
> ...
> ```

Строки `without flush` появляются целиком через две секунды. Строки `with flash` появляются сразу, к ним по одной добавляются точки в течении двух секунд.